# What is the difference in meaning between "commission" and "fee"?

Tags: differences

I have a case where a certain amount of money is paid to a payment system for the transaction (like if you send money overseas you pay like $20 per transaction to a SWIFT company).

My colleague translated this as "fee" and this seem to be ok. But somehow this looks like more a "commission" to me.

What is the difference in meaning between these terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [OED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/commission)  says **commission** is:

> ...typically a set percentage of the value involved

As for **fee**, it is described in the same source as:

> 1.1 Money paid as part of a special transaction, for example for a privilege or for admission to something.

and thus implies payment necessary to get entrance for transaction (i.e., you have to pay something to enter a bank transaction).

The easiest way of charging a fee during a bank transaction is taking percentage (commission). According to the 1st link above in OED 'commission' is commonly used to refer to percentage in money transactions.

But I guess if no percentage is involved, it's appropriate to use 'fee' as well. So the situation and technicalities should apply.

Comment: Agreed.  A commission is a percentage-based charge.  Technically a commission is a fee, but it's more common (at least in the English spoken where I live, in western Canada) to call specified, non-percentage charges a fee, although sometimes people call that a "flat fee" to ensure that people understand it's a set amount and not variable.